# Xamarin Forms : Drawing a line under listview

Tags: xamarin.forms

Dears,

I need to draw a Blue line under listview like the following picture:

[image]

My code is:

```
<StackLayout>
                <Image
                Source="blue_holo_circle.png">
         <ListView>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout
                               items inside listview like profile,name,time,like etc>
                    </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
   </StackLayout>
```

I know the code for drawing a line using BoxView :

```
     <BoxView  
           VerticalOptions="Fill"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           WidthRequest="1"
           Color="Blue"/>
```

But I don't know where I need to add the code for the line, I try to add before listview, but the line is not coming under the list.

Anybody suggest a solution for drawing a line under the list items(listview)?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: I am telling about the the vertical blue line covers the entire page. Which is a single line, but when the list items come the line comes under the data. Actually there is only one line, not 3.

Comment: Are you talking about the blue box that contains the thumb and flag icons?

Comment: Not that box, my line starting from the top. There is a blue holo circle in the top, line start from the center bottom of it and comes under the list item then touching the profile picture. Then it going under the list item and continuing after the list item.

Comment: Ah the vertical line. I was confused when you said under the listview

Comment: Any suggestion to achieve this?

Comment: Yes use a grid like the answer suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        HasUnevenRows="True">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Padding="20">
                        <StackLayout Padding="5" BackgroundColor="LimeGreen">
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}" 
                             Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}" 
                             Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                        <BoxView  
                               VerticalOptions="Fill"
                               HorizontalOptions="Start"
                               WidthRequest="1"
                               Color="Blue"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

// Code Behind

```
public partial class ListViewPage1 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

    public ListViewPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4",
            "Item 5"
        };

        BindingContext = this;
    }
  }
```

Try like this....

Answer (score 0):

Better use Grid to your requirement , it will be very useful and easy to understand the design we are up to.

Answer (score 0):

This Resolved my Problem.

```xml
     <StackLayout>
           <BoxView HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White" />
    </StackLayout>
```

I used it in the Grid.

```xml
     <Grid BackgroundColor="#0073E0">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="20" />
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
          <BoxView HeightRequest="1" VerticalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="White"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
```